# If data object not found VBA gives 1004 error in 1 line code

Tags: excel, vba

I have below VBA code in place which is just to clear filters in excel. The table starts from row 7 that is why Range A7 select is there. But in case there are no filters in place then when I run macro it gives Runtime error 1004.

I want it to not throw any error when there are no errors

```
    Sub clearfilter()
     ' ' clearfilter Macro '
    
    '
    
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Range("A1").Select
        
    End Sub
```

clear filters but VBA giving error